# How can I copy rows from one to another table with a different colnm data

Tags: mysql, database

---

### I had two tables Table 1 & Table 2 AS shown here

Table:1

| ID | IMG_PATH | CAT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 166 | hfhbf | 1 |
| 164 | jgj | 2 |
| 162 | ggd | 1 |
| 160 | mfnf | 1 |
| 158 | dbd | 2 |

Table:2

| ID | IMG_PARENT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| Here I want to print table 1's ID column data Example:166 | Here (ID-1) Example:165 |
| Here I want to print table 1's ID column data Example:164 | Here (ID-1) Example:163 |
| Here I want to print table 1's ID column data Example:162 | Here (ID-1) Example:161 |
| Here I want to print table 1's ID column data Example:160 | Here (ID-1) Example:159 |
| Here I want to print table 1's ID column data Example:158 | Here (ID-1) Example:157 |

### AS SHOWN IN TABLE 2 I NEED FOLLOWING VALUE...

and dont try this manually method:
INSERT INTO tabla2
SELECT * FROM tabla1
WHERE id = 1 //Here we write the condition

### I want to fetch data because arround 10,000's row are inserted in this table

Lots of tries but didnt get it

Comment: `INSERT INTO table2 SELECT id, id-1 FROM table1`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

based on what you provided info about your question, this is what I understand about this.
Assuming that `table 1` is auto_increment with ID of 1-10,000.

Then you can use this to select the even IDs in `table 1` and insert it to `table 2`

```
insert into table2 (ID) select ID from table1 group by ID having mod(ID, 2) = 0;
```

To select odd IDs from `table 1` and insert it to `table 2` you can use this

```
insert into table2 (IMG_PARENT_ID) select ID from table1 group by ID having mod(ID, 2) = 1;
```